# Presentation Tool for AngularJS available in Bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, presentation

Does anyone know of a presentation tool like [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) for angular?

I found [angular-showoff](https://github.com/tchatel/angular-showoff) but I wanted some available via bower.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the 2 close votes as being off-topic for programming. I'm looking for an angular module available via bower to use as a dependency on a project, not a presentation app like powerpoint

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: You can still get angular-showoff with bower: `bower install tchatel/angular-showoff`. You'll just have to be careful with versioning. In cases where a repo doesn't have (semver) version numbers I've typically forked and tagged it myself.

Comment: @jtrussell yes but that project is not built to be used as a dependency, I'd have to check if the directives I need have any internal dependencies, and keep all that updated.

Comment: https://github.com/mhevery/ng-slides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ricardo,

Yea there is an other option. You can use **Impress.JS** with angularJS.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div id="impresshook" ng-app="impressjs">
    <div class="impress">
        <div class="step slide" 
        ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"
        data-x="{{((i%2)-1) * 800}}"
        data-y="{{(i%4) * 800}}"
        data-z="{{-i * 500}}"
        data-rotate-x="{{((i%2)-1) * 10}}"
        data-rotate-y="{{((i%6)-1) * 40}}"
        data-rotate-z="{{i * -10}}">
            <h1>{{i}}</h1>
            <p>
            <button ng-click="$emit('previousSlide')">Previous</button>
            <button ng-click="$emit('nextSlide')">Next</button>
            </p>
            <p>Or Left / Right Arrows</p>

        </div>
        <div class="step" data-y="1500">
            <button ng-click="$emit('nextSlide')">Start Over</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/eprouver/LAhGH/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the option that's more easy to directly integrate with a existing angular app.

Answer (score 2):

[Bespoke.js](https://github.com/markdalgleish/bespoke.js) is a super minimal (1KB), modular presentation library for modern browsers, designed to foster a rich plugin ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one which is available via bower [Applause.](https://github.com/Granze/applause)

There are good feature in it like presenter mode, PDF export, configurable via JSON file, etc.

[**Demo Link**](http://granze.github.io/applause/)

> **NOTE**
>
> This project is at an early stage of development.